# How to take two cell reference from another sheet in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am not able to take the reference from column AB and AC given in sheet ("UPDATER") to sheet("Historical_vol"), can anyone please confirm what am i doing wrong here ?

```
Sub historical_vol()
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'This will help to watch the status bar update
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim wb As Workbook, uPd As Worksheet, hV As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long, cl As Range
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set uPd = wb.Sheets("UPDATER")
Set hV = wb.Sheets("Historical_vol")
uPd.Activate
uPd.Range("AD4:AG4", Range("AD4").End(xlDown)).Clear
lr = uPd.Cells(Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row
i = 0
For i = 4 To lr
hV.Range("A9:B9").Value = uPd.Range("AB" & i & ":AC" & i).Value
hV.Calculate
DoEvents
uPd.Range("AD" & i & ":AG" & i).Value = hV.Range("C9:F9").Value
Application.StatusBar = i - 3 & " / " & lr - 3
'View on status bar number of records completed out of total records (lr-3)
Next i
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

UPDATER SHEET

[image]

HISTORICAL_VOL SHEET

[image]

Comment: Also, how can i copy 5 rows each from updater sheet to historical sheet till last row

Comment: Presumably you meant to write 5 columns, but you haven't said where (i.e. from what row) on the HISTORICAL_VOL sheet the data should be copied to?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line

```
For Each cl In uPd.Range("AB4:AC4" & lr)
```

to

```
For Each cl In uPd.Range("AB4:AC" & lr).Rows
```

and the line

```
cl.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 4).Value = hV.Range("C9:F9").Value
```

to

```
cl.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 3).Value = hV.Range("C9:F9").Value
```

Comment: Hi Spectral, it seems it is still picking value from column AB (from updater sheet) as i can see in immediate window ? cl = SIEGn.DE, it should have taken pkey as well from column AC and pasted it in historical_vol sheet in cell (A9:B9)

Comment: Please edit the code in your post, so that I can see _how_ you have updated it.

Comment: edited the original code

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer, as there was an actual error in your code ("AB4:AC4"->"AB4:AC") - please update your code, and try again, i.e. in the first iteration of the loop, advise what was written to A9 and B9 of the HISTORICAL_VOL sheet

Comment: sorry but still no luck :(

Comment: 'no luck' is 'no help' from a debugging perspective - please answer the question I asked in my previous comment.

Comment: i made some changes in the code and it worked, posting the updated code